# How to pull back which students got all 4's for grades?

Tags: mysql

I have 400+ students who have a range of 1-4 for scores across their courses. Students can take anywhere from 3-6 courses.  How can I read through the data and pull back only those students who got a score of '4' on all their grades. I'm thinking some type of ranking function, but it's not coming to me.

I have this code which builds a temp table and gives me a list of each student (along with other data) with their score for each grade. Now I need to go through one row at a time and identify those students who only have 4's for all courses.

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTableHonors
FROM
(
SELECT id.lastName + ', ' + id.firstName + COALESCE(' ' + LEFT(id.middleName,1),'') AS 'student'
, p.stateID
, cust.value AS RTAdvisor
, en.grade
, cs.name as ClassName
, gs1.score
, gt1.name
FROM Enrollment en 
    JOIN Person p on en.personID = p.personID
    JOIN [Identity] id on p.currentIdentityID = id.identityID and p.personID = id.personID
    JOIN Trial tr ON tr.calendarID = en.calendarID AND tr.active = 1
    JOIN Roster rs ON rs.personID = en.personID AND rs.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Section sc ON sc.sectionID = rs.sectionID AND sc.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Course cs ON cs.courseID = sc.courseID AND cs.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN ScheduleStructure ss ON ss.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN TermSchedule ts ON ts.structureID = ss.structureID
    JOIN Term tm ON tm.termScheduleID = ts.termScheduleID AND tm.seq = 1
    JOIN (GradingScore gs1 JOIN GradingTask gt1 ON gt1.taskID = gs1.taskID)
        ON gs1.calendarID = en.calendarID AND gs1.personID = en.personID AND gs1.sectionID = sc.sectionID AND gs1.termID = tm.termID
    LEFT JOIN customstudent cust on cust.personID = p.personID and cust.attributeID = 321
WHERE 1=1 
    AND en.calendarID = 1054
    AND en.serviceType = 'P'
   -- AND en.endDate is null
    AND (gt1.name = 'Quarter - Habits of Work')
group by id.lastName + ', ' + id.firstName + COALESCE(' ' + LEFT(id.middleName,1),'')
, p.stateID
, cust.value
, en.grade
, cs.name
, gs1.score
, gt1.name
) AS x
```

Comment: Get all the students who don't have 'not 4'

Comment: Your query includes *many* more tables than are accounted for by your description. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, because I'm pulling many more fields, but only showed those applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
SELECT student
  FROM ( ... query that returns students and score ... )
 GROUP
    BY student
HAVING MIN(score) = 4
;
```

So, for example, if the `... query that returns students and score ...` part returns something like this:

```
 student | score
---------+-------
 Jim     |     4
 Jim     |     3
 Kara    |     4
 Kara    |     4
```

then the overall query will return this:

```
 student
---------
 Kara
```

Comment: Thank you! It did just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about this. One method:

Imagine a table

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| student | course | grade |
+---------+--------+-------+
|       1 | a      |     4 |
|       1 | b      |     4 |
|       1 | c      |     3 |
|       1 | d      |     4 |
|       2 | a      |     4 |
|       2 | b      |     4 |
|       2 | d      |     4 |
|       3 | a      |     4 |
|       3 | b      |     4 |
|       3 | c      |     4 |
|       3 | d      |     3 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

1. Grab all of the students that have records that are not a 4:

   `SELECT student FROM grades WHERE grade <> 4 GROUP BY student;`
2. Then get a list of students that aren't in that list

   `SELECT student FROM grades WHERE student NOT IN (SELECT student FROM grades WHERE grade <> 4 GROUP BY student);`

Comment: Why not a join for the 2nd part?

Comment: Don't really need anything from the subquery, so a join seems overkill. I mean... I guess it depends how the parser goes after it and what the execution path is. I'm guessing from all the joins in OP's query that @ruakh answer might be less demanding then either a `JOIN` or a `NOT IN`.

Comment: I see. Found [something interesting](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: That's a nice article. I would totally have guessed that `NOT EXISTS` is not efficient (or at least it was 7 years ago) especially since they were using a correlated subquery.

Comment: How can I get the execution time of a query?

Comment: Thank you! Both of these worked. And that was an interesting article - I've bookmarked it - thank you!